# Ansible SNOW Module

Tags: ansible

How can we add multiple Configuration Items (CIs) in ServiceNow incident using ansible snow_record module? I tried looping multiple CIs in snow_record-> data-> cmdb_ci but it appears to update only one CI in the ticket and not adding multiple CIs in the Affected CIs list.

```
- snow_record:
    username: "{{ snow_user }}"
    password: "{{ snow_password }}"
    instance: "{{ snow_instance }}"
    state: present
    number: "INC0XXX"
    data:
      cmdb_ci: example1.com
  #loop: 
  #  - example1.com
  #  - example2.com
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, welcome to SO. Have you tried setting it to a list of the values, as in `cmdb_ci: ["example1.com", "example2.com"]`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks or your response. I tried passing the cmdb_ci: as an array but it adds an empty CI in the ticket incited of any of the array items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution, actually cmdb_ci: is for adding the primary CI in the ticket. To add additional CIs we need to use task_ci table and pass the additional CI name and the ticket number, it is working fine now. :)

```
- snow_record:
   username: "{{ snow_user }}"
   password: "{{ snow_password }}"
   instance: "{{ snow_instance }}"
   state: present
   table: task_ci
   data:
    ci_item: "{{ item }}" 
    task: "INCXXXX"
  loop: 
    - example1.com
    - example2.com
```